# How to Unit Test Type Hint with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test this method:

**Class:**

```
public function bind(\Elastica\ResultSet $result = null) {

    if (!$result instanceof \Elastica\ResultSet) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('I need an instance of \Elastica\ResultSet');
    }

    $this->bindedData = $result->getResults();
    $this->isBinded = true;
}
```

**Test**

```
public function testGetTransformedDataNotSuccesful() {

    $this->object->bind(new \stdClass()); //This throws a Catchable fatal error

}
```

My question is:

How can i test this?

An alternative is not to Type Hint the method var.

Or shouldn't i test this.

Wouldn't it make sense that PHP throws an exception instead of throwing a fatal error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing a fatal error is correct, as your method signature explicitly asks for a \Elastica\ResultSet but you provide an \stdClass.

Removing the typehint would also remove the fatal error - but that doesn't make much sense imho :)

**edit**

This test should pass

```
public function testGetTransformedDataNotSuccesful() {
    $this->setExpectedException(get_class(new PHPUnit_Framework_Error("",0,"",1)));

    $this->object->bind(new \stdClass()); //This throws a Catchable fatal error

}
```

Comment: *updated the answers* Well, the problem stays the same. You're strongly type-hinting to \Elastica\ResultSet but you're passing a stdclass(); What else should happen :)

Comment: I don't know. I hope that php throws and exception an not a catchable fatal error or something like this. So my question was -
Is this testable as a PHPUnit test ? Do you know what i mean ?

Comment: It IS testable (you can use setExpectedException() and look for the PHPUnit Exception) but it doesn't make sense, because PHP takes care of that internally. It like checking that the + operator sums up two numbers.

Comment: No im confused. I think a catchable fatal error is not an exception ? Its not just about if this makes sense for me - it's a general question.

Comment: AFAIK PHPUnit overrides the internal PHP error handler and throwes every notice, warning, error etc. as a `PHPUnit_Framework_Error`. So you can check if that error is thrown. But again: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: For me it would make more sense that php throws an exception in that case.I saw that php stops excecution of the script when this happens () so i can be sure that it can't be exceuted. Thanks for your help...

Comment: Is this code still applicable for PHP7 (where a `TypeError` exception is thrown instead of a fatal error)?
Also, the `get_class(...)` can be replaced with `PHPUnit_Framework_Error::class`